# Uploaded files validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I need to validate files that are uploaded through the WebApi post request (for a file extension and filesize). 
As I can see web.config file allows to restrict extension and files size for IIS via  and  options, but I also added some code validation. Is it ok to have both IIS and code validation? What's the best practice?

Comment: I think the server configuration has the higher priority. Let's say you configured a maximum file size of 10mb in your web.config, IIS will block uploads bigger than this size even if your code validation accepts 15mb. The best approach imho is to setup the very maximum file size the server could possibly receive within web.config for the context of your application and check everything smaller in the code.